# get_post_meta property of non object

Tags: posts, custom-field

I am getting a custom field outside the loop in header.php. I get the custom field just fine but I found that when the custom field is empty, I get an error message

```
  Trying to get property of non-object
```

Here is my code

```
 <?php $description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'page-description', true ); ?>
            <div id="page-title">
            <?php if( !empty($description)) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
```

I did some searching on this site and one post said to globalize the $post variable. I tried that but didn't work. I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Upon further review. I don't think there is anything wrong with my code. I am only getting it on one page which doesn't make any sense. So I must be getting the wrong line as the error.

Comment: Try using if( $description != '') instead of if( !empty($description))

Comment: On which page are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'page-description', true ); ?>
                <div id="page-title">
            <?php if( $description !='' ) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
```